# fullpage.js how to detect vertical scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am building a page with a few "stages" which the **[fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)** plugin provides.

My main problem is that I need to apply a fixed position header, which by default I do by using a simple script that I use for most of the cases so far. And here it is:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
  var a = $(this).scrollTop()
  if (a > 5) {
$('header').addClass('headerSnap')
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass('headerSnap')
  }
});
```

I simply calculate the viewport offset ammount and tell it to append a class to the header using a fixed position. But here the problem is that fullpage.js does not allow my simple script to detect an offset, so therefore the class is not being applied.

What can I do to bypass this issue?

Comment: fullpage.js has an optional `fixedElements`. That should do everything you need

Comment: this way I will be forced to add more markup for the internal pages for another header, because they are not planned to be built with fullpage.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to sort it out for myself, I simply added a scrollbar from its settings as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
      scrollBar: true,
    });
});
```

This way my script works, since it has a scollbar to follow.

> **NOTE:** This answers my ***specific question***, which is not an overall solution for fixed headers. Please re-read my first post for further information on this.

Comment: You could also add the class `headerSnap` on the `onLeave` callback if you want to keep the scroll bar hidden.

Answer (score 0):

`onLeave` using `nextIndex`argument wise you can addClass or removeClass

```
<div id="main-section">
   <div class="section-one">Sectioin 1</div>
   <div class="section-two">Sectioin 2</div>
   <div class="section-three">Sectioin 3</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery('#main-section').fullpage({
            sectionsColor: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'],
              onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){        
                  console.log(nextIndex);
                    if(nextIndex == 1){
                        jQuery('header').removeClass('headerSnap');
                    }else{
                       jQuery('header').addClass('headerSnap');     
                    }
               }
         });
    });
    </script>
```

Second option is every main section you can add one class name then you can detect section via setInterval and hasClass

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         jQuery('#main-section').fullpage({
              sectionsColor: ['red', 'orange', 'yellow'],
          });

        setInterval(function() {
          if(jQuery('.section-one').hasClass('fp-completely')){
             alert('section 1');
          }
          if(jQuery('.section-two').hasClass('fp-completely')){
             alert('section 2');
          }
        }, 500);
    });
    </script>
```